# _stat alternative in visual c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I have an SDK sample in VC++ and i am writing code in c#. In VC++ sample they have used

```
struct  _stat StatBuff;
```

When i checked the definition of _stat it is

```
#define _stat  _stat64i32
```

They are using StatBuff as

```
unsigned int BuffSize = StatBuff.st_size + 8;
```

This code is intended to create a buffer for a browsed image file, next line is

```
ImageBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc( BuffSize );
```

i am wondering that how i can convert (StatBuff.st_size) in c#, i have searched a lot on internet but could not convert this piece of code. Can i use some alternate c# function.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what the purpose of the code is?

Comment: #nvoigt i have edited the question

Comment: Maybe you can post a larger block, because there are simple image loading functions in C#, there is no need to fiddle with low level byte calculations.

Comment: This is probably a poor choice of code to get started with, _stat() is a Unix function that maps pretty poorly to Windows file systems.  So do image file formats, I'd imagine.  Still, _stat.st_size isn't a problem, it is the same as FileInfo.Length.  And malloc() should not slow you down, it is new byte[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various [`_stat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) functions are C/C++ library wrappers around underlying Win32 functions designed to make porting from Posix like OSs easier.

Using an offset like +8 is making assumptions about the internal layout of the `_stat` type that could change.

All the information is available in the .NET [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileinfo) type.

Comment: Richard i am confused because _stat has properties like buffer and and path and resulting ImageBuffer finally i have to pass to another SDK function. My question is that either i should make my on class with same attributes or can use FileInfo Directly.

Comment: @Tanveer That is impossible to answer without much more detailed knowledge of the code. You are likely to be better off (1) understanding what the code does, (2) re-writing using .NET equivalents. Such a re-writing will *not* be a one-statement to one-statement translation.